# Access query combine two tables with criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery, where-clause, having

The below code references two tables. Each table are identical in structure, only difference being the "PRICE" and "PRICE_DATE" values. This is because it's the same table created one year ago. All I want to do is have a new table which takes the latest price in each table for each fund and inserts that into a new table. In addition to this, I also want another column which calculates the growth. 
The code below works for this purpose.

```
SELECT [2015_11_Fund_Prices].FUND_CODE, [2015_11_Fund_Prices].PRICE AS 
[PRICE_@_112015], [2016_11_Fund_Prices].PRICE AS [PRICE_@_112016]
([2016_11_Fund_Prices].[PRICE]/[2015_11_Fund_Prices].[PRICE]-1) AS Growth INTO 2016_11_Monthly_Fund_Prices
FROM 2016_11_Fund_Prices INNER JOIN 2015_11_Fund_Prices ON [2016_11_Fund_Prices].FUND_CODE = [2015_11_Fund_Prices].FUND_CODE
GROUP BY [2015_11_Fund_Prices].FUND_CODE, [2015_11_Fund_Prices].PRICE_DATE, [2015_11_Fund_Prices].PRICE, [2016_11_Fund_Prices].PRICE, [2016_11_Fund_Prices].PRICE_DATE, ([2016_11_Fund_Prices].[PRICE]/[2015_11_Fund_Prices].[PRICE]-1)
HAVING ((([2015_11_Fund_Prices].PRICE_DATE)=#24/11/2015#) AND (([2016_11_Fund_Prices].PRICE_DATE)=#24/11/2016#));
```

However, this code assumes that the latest price is 24/11 in both tables. I want to replace this with a max function that will result in the query referencing only the price in the row with the highest date value.

Can anyone help?
Tabels used are

```
    +-----------+------------+-------+
    | Fund_Code | PRICE_DATE | PRICE |
    +-----------+------------+-------+
    |         1 | 12/12/12   | 1     |
    |         1 | 13/12/12   | 1.2   |
    |         1 | 14/12/12   | 1.1   |
    |         2 | 12/12/12   | 1.12  |
    |         2 | 13/12/12   | 1.13  |
    |         2 | 14/12/12   | 1.11  |
```

So the second table is exactly the same but dates corresponding to the following year. 
All I want is a table with:

```
Fund_Code Price1 Price2 Growth
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a sub-query like this:

```
SELECT FUND_CODE, MAX(PRICE_DATE) AS MaxPriceDate FROM 2016_11_Fund_Prices GROUP BY FUND_CODE
```

If you add this sub-query to the above and link it to the `2016_11_Fund_Prices` table on `FUND_CODE` and `PRICE_DATE=MaxPriceDate` it should do what you need.

```
SELECT 2016_11_Fund_Prices.FUND_CODE, PRICE, PRICE_DATE
FROM 2016_11_Fund_Prices
    INNER JOIN (SELECT FUND_CODE, MAX(PRICE_DATE) AS MaxPriceDate FROM 2016_11_Fund_Prices GROUP BY FUND_CODE) mp
        ON 2016_11_Fund_Prices.FUND_CODE=mp.FUND_CODE AND 2016_11_Fund_Prices.PRICE_DATE=mp.MaxPriceDate
```

Comment: So you're suggesting having two queries to generate the result? I thought it would be possible in one.

Comment: Also, why is it that when I add "SELECT PRICE" into your above code, the results return all dates again rather than just the max?

Comment: You can add it as a sub-query to your existing query but it will be less complicated to troubleshoot if you use it as a separate query. Just adding SELECT PRICE should give you an error as you are neither aggregating nor grouping by PRICE. If you are adding PRICE to the grouping as well it would make sense that you are getting all the dates as you are now grouping on every single price instead of just each FUND_CODE; which is why you have to use it as a separate subquery and can't try to shortcut it by just adding the PRICE to it.

Comment: I updated my solution with the full sub-query to get the latest 2016 Price

Comment: OK I understand. So you're suggesting that I do this for both tables first and then combine thereafter? So 3 queries altogether? This is something I already knew how to do. It was trying to get it into 1 Query was where I was struggling. I do appreciate your help massively!

Comment: If you have a design reason to make it all one massive query, it can be done, you will just find yourself in parenthesis hell. However depending on what you are most comfortable with and how much this is a process you will have to add another set of tables to at the end of 2017, you may want to consider keeping it as broken down as possible, maybe to the point where each step is simple enough to be done with the GUI (as saved independent queries) instead of SQL.

Comment: Thanks again for the help. I suppose I will just have to split into 3. Could you please explain why changing the #dd/mm/yyyy# in the Having clause to a max(table.price_date) wouldn't work? Thanks

Comment: Because as long as you also have `PRICE` in the `GROUP BY` `Max(PRICE_DATE)` only gives you the max date for that one specific `PRICE`.

Comment: I've added the tables to my answer as I'm almost certain there is an easier way! I don't mean to stay on this I just believe this should be do able as the principle is quite simple! Thanks